# Ionic collection-repeat can't scroll to bottom

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When using collection-repeat, I can only scroll till the middle of last element. However refreshing the page fixes the problem.
Here's what I have in my markup:

```
<ion-list ng-show="vm.models.length > 0">
    <ion-item collection-repeat="model in vm.models"
              item-height="200px" item-width="100%"
              ui-sref="app.state">
        <img ng-src="{{ model.image.uri }}">
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And here's what I get: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKaW6.png)

Have to say, that ng-repeat works alright. I've checked css, everything is alright there. Here's what I see in inspector though:

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="model in vm.models" item-height="200px" item-width="100%" ui-sref="app.state" href="#/state/url/param/" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 600px, 0px); height: 201px; width: 412px;"><a class="item-content">...</ion-item>

<ion-item collection-repeat="model in vm.models" item-height="200px" item-width="100%" ui-sref="app.state" href="#/state/url//" style="transform: translate3d(-9999px, -9999px, 0px); height: 0px; width: 0px;"><a class="item-content">...</ion-item>
```

Notice empty 'param' in href, and I see numbers of "empty" elements like that after last element in the list

Comment: Can you provide a codepen example ? From what I'm seeing, page header padding hides a portion of your first image, thus messes up width total height calculation specific to collection-repeat. But I can not be sure unless I see it in action.

Comment: Nah, there're images before, the screenshot is taken at the bottom of the page, and there is no padding

Answer (score 0):

Make your won scroll scope :

Try this :

> ```
> <ion-scroll direction="y" style="width: 100%; height:400px;">
>     <ion-list ng-show="vm.models.length > 0">
>         <ion-item collection-repeat="model in vm.models"
>                   item-height="200px" item-width="100%"
>                   ui-sref="app.state">
>             <img ng-src="{{ model.image.uri }}">
>          </ion-item>
>     </ion-list>
>     </ion-scroll>
> ```